# Unable to install Kodi Krypton 17.3

Tags: release-loki, software-installation

Today i took the jump to Linux on a little home media PC. Trying to install Kodi Krypton 17.3 but i keep only getting the old version?
I followed this guide http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux but it does not matter what i do i am unable to get krypton installed.

I came across this https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629646 and i think i tried this and then re-tried the install but same result.

If anyone can help, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in my case (with loki and now with juno) I didn't have any issues installing kodi

my current apt source

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/team-xbmc-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
```

--

to get it I just added the repo

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
$ sudo apt update
```

(newer apt doesn't need update, after you add a repo it will update itself)

and then

```
$ sudo apt install kodi
```

it's even on ubuntu's repo for bionic (juno)

```
$ apt policy kodi
kodi:
  Instalados: 2:17.6+git20180430.1623-final-0bionic
  Candidato:  2:17.6+git20180430.1623-final-0bionic
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 2:17.6+git20180430.1623-final-0bionic 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

--

**Now to chek your system just use this command. That way we can see what version you have available and from where**

```
$ apt policy kodi
```

--

PS: If add-apt-repository isn't found or you get an error, probably you need to install software-properties-common first, then run it again

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue...the app center only had version 15.2 of kodi which shocked me...if it's already installed then i would suggest uninstalling it first then use the terminal to re-install kodi...not sure why but i couldn't get kodi to upgrade until i uninstalled kodi 15.2 first

k